# Split array into subarrays by columns in R, each with a different number of columns

Tags: r, sub-array

I have been at this for a while, but seem to be having issues.

I am looking to tweak the following small script that I've developed so that the output of 'pop' consists of smaller subarrays, each with different number of columns (but same number of rows). When K = 1, there is just one array. If K > 1, I would like there to be K subarrays in the 'pop' variable.

```
K <- 1 # number of arrays
N <- 10 # number of columns
Hstar <- 5 # maximum label value in array
perms <- 10 # number of rows

probs <- rep(1/Hstar, Hstar)

specs <- 1:N

pop <- array(dim = c(c(perms, N), K))

haps <- as.character(1:Hstar)

for(j in 1:perms){
    for(i in 1:K){
        pop[j, specs, i] <- sample(haps, size = N, replace = TRUE, prob = probs)
    }
}

pop
, , 1

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,] "4"  "5"  "4"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "2"  "3"  "2"  "1"  
 [2,] "5"  "5"  "4"  "4"  "2"  "2"  "1"  "3"  "5"  "4"  
 [3,] "1"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "4"  "4"  "5"  "4"  "2"  "2"  
 [4,] "5"  "4"  "4"  "3"  "3"  "1"  "4"  "3"  "3"  "5"  
 [5,] "3"  "1"  "5"  "2"  "5"  "1"  "3"  "1"  "2"  "2"  
 [6,] "1"  "2"  "5"  "3"  "2"  "4"  "1"  "5"  "5"  "4"  
 [7,] "5"  "5"  "2"  "3"  "3"  "3"  "1"  "1"  "2"  "3"  
 [8,] "4"  "2"  "4"  "3"  "1"  "1"  "2"  "3"  "2"  "1"  
 [9,] "5"  "5"  "5"  "5"  "3"  "1"  "4"  "4"  "3"  "5"  
[10,] "1"  "1"  "5"  "4"  "4"  "3"  "4"  "2"  "4"  "3"
```

In the above output, I would like to divide 'pop' by columns, so that each new subarray contains the same number of rows, but different numbers of columns.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind providing some sample matrices that match your intended output. I want to make sure I understand the desired output for pop. Does the slicing of 'pop' occur inside the loop, or do you just need to develop subsets of the final 'pop' output of your function. `combn()` appears to be similar to what you need.

Comment: @jacobsg I'd like the slicing to occur in the loop (as long as it doesn't affect runtime too much), otherwise I think there are alternatives. For the matrices,  there are many possibilities for output e.g., (10 x 1), (10 x 2), ... (10, c), where c is the number of columns. In my example, c = 10.